# Classifying groups of stocks beyond Market Cap/Industry/Sector

Tags: equities, portfolio-management, portfolio, margin

I'm monitoring margin values for a portfolio and I want to classify the stocks in my universe using different metrics/information. Just for the sake of making analysis/inferences on the data I have.

So far, I've categorized it by: Sector, Industry, Exchange, Currency and Market Cap.

But I'm not sure what other information I can use to continue categorizing the portfolio.

Can you suggest metrics or/and resources related to this? I'm not sure where to look for exactly.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always turn to unsupervised machine learning and apply hierarchical clustering and then plot the relationships using a dendrogram.

There is a cool portfolio optimization paper that uses Hierarchical Risk Parity to optimize a portfolio. That's the source from which I drew this inspiration.

[Building Diversified Portfolios that Outperform Out-of-Sample](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2708678)

It will group similar stocks together based on the relationships derived from their price data. I think you will be presently surprised.

Comment: Thanks for this valuable resources Jacques! Indeed will be very valuable :)